# Can i update joomla1.5 having Virtuemart 1.1.4 to joomla 2.5 ( Virtuemart have many custom code )

Tags: joomla1.5, upgrade, virtuemart, joomla2.5

I have a site which have joomla 1.5 having virtuemart 1.1.4 where virtuemart is having many customizations. Also i have some other components but my main customization is in virtuemart so is this possible that i upgrade my joomla from 1.5 to 2.5 and also virtuemart work with it with all customization i did ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, It will not be a good idea to upgrade the joomla and virtuemart. There are lots of changes has been made in both joomla and virtuemart so it can create a lot of problem in case you upgrade these.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So is there any posibility that i can upgrade to 1.6 or 1.7 ? Or i can't update it at all as the new joomla have many new things in it so

Comment: ya every version have some new feature so if you modified any in the current version that will not be available in the upgraded version so if you want to keep your modification as it is.Then please don't upgrade and start thing from scratch always....

Comment: Thank you very much I will not go for upgrading it.